# Retrieving Claims in OIDC and MVC

Tags: owin, openid-connect

I have a controller with the following line of code:

```
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
```

In my Startup.Auth.cs, I have the following:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "",
            ClientSecret = "",
            Scope = "openid email profile",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, IdpInstance, "common", "/v2.0"),
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost/abcdeg.ClaimsAdapter.WebApp/Oidc/Authenticate",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/"),
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorization,
                SecurityTokenValidated = OnTokenValidate,
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
            },

        });
```

Within the OnTokenValidate, is where I should be getting my claims, I'm assuming. If so, how would I go about it. I know I have a SecurityTokenValidatedNotification, but none of the methods or members of that object seem to expose anything related to Claims. I need to somehow store these claims so that I may retrieve it on my Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Generally for a server side web app, the above Microsoft library will by default just use claims returned in the id token. These claims originate from your Authorization Server.

The place to customize the logic is during the AuthorizationCodeReceived handler. Commonly you will:

- Create a new authentication ticket
- Customize its claims
- The claims will then be serialized to your authentication cookie
- Every subsequent request to your app will deserialize the cookie

Common things to do are:

- Add the refresh token to your claims
- Add other claims from outside the id token
- Perhaps add claims that you read from a database or another API

There is some example code here to get you started:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2457

Comment: Hey Gary, thanks for the reply! I'm wondering if I should used AuthorizationCodeReceived for two reasons. 1. the responseType is id_token, so it's using the implicit workflow, so I wonder if the authorizationCodeReceived is even called in that case. 2. I actually already tried adding the example code in, and I'm still having problems seeing the Claims. I'm trying to access the claims in the url indicated in the ReturnUri....any idea how to do that? ClaimsPrincipal doesn't show the claims at all for some reason

Comment: Hey Gary, have you seen this? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I see:

**DESIGN CONSIDERATIONS**

- Generally the MS libraries are designed for the server side Authorization Code Flow and you use response type = 'code id_token'
- The Implicit Flow instead uses 'token id_token' and I don't think the above libraries support that flow
- Also, if you need to call APIs after login you will need to get a 'code' so that you can then get access tokens

UPSHOT: If using the above libraries I would recommend using 'code id_token' - it might fix your problem.

**WHAT IS RETURNED OVER THE WIRE?**

Can you see what is returned in the id token (via an [Online JWT viewer](https://jwt.io))? This should be where  your claims originate from.

**IMPLICIT FLOW**

This is implemented in Javascript code in the UI rather than in server side code. There is some stuff about this on a tutorial based blog I am writing:

- [Implicit Flow Messages](http://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) - see Steps 4 and 7 for login requests + responses

Comment: It seems like there are a lot of libraries owin provides. I just don't know how to use them. Like AuthorizationCodeReceived, it seems like it is only called when you used the [Authorized] attribute. It won't get called if you do a regular HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);